# Taiga 'i586-linux-gnu-gcc': No such file or directory

Tags: python, linux, gcc, debian, taiga

I am trying to install taiga (scrum tool) on our project-server (debian 6.0)

Installation Guide:

http://taigaio.github.io/taiga-doc/dist/setup-production.html

So far i came to the point:

Install dependencies

> pip install -r requirements.txt

There i get following error:

> i586-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall
>   -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.5.4 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1
>   -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090401 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.4/server -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o
>   build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o
>   -Wdeclaration-after-statement
>
> unable to execute 'i586-linux-gnu-gcc': No such file or directory
>
> error: command 'i586-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
>
> ---------------------------------------- Cleaning up... Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools,
>   tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-build-mEfjyg/psycopg2/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**,
>   'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-BX4WIW-record/install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-mEfjyg/psycopg2 Storing debug log for failure in
>   /root/.pip/pip.log

Is there a way to fix this?

PS:

python-dev is installed

commented the last line in requirements.txt (enum34==1.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this error and solved installing package minwg32 and dependencys (linux)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have `gcc` installed?

https://packages.debian.org/jessie/i386/gcc/filelist